# .NET CORE_Blazor Cannot find Http.SendAsJsonAsync()

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, blazor

Please I have trying to call my web API request in .Net Core Blazor project. I cannot seem to find Http.SendAsJsonAsync what I have is Http.SendAsAsync Please what do I need to do? Does this mean that in 3.1 we cannot use SendAsJsonAsync or am I missing out a particular reference?

Please find the image screenshot and code below.

[image]

The sample code is here:

```
@page "/counter"
@using BlazeCRUD.Models;
@using BlazeCRUD.Services;
@using System.Net.Http;
@inject HttpClient Http
@inherits OwningComponentBase<BlazeServices>



<h3><b>New Loan Application</b></h3>

<p></p>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input for="Name" class="form-control" bind="" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label">Department</label>
                <input asp-for="Department" class="form-control" bind="" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">Save</button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@code  {

    Performanceappuser pc = new Performanceappuser();

    protected async Task AddLoanApplication()
    {

        await Http.
    }

    List<Performanceappuser> pau;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        pau = Service.appUser();
    }

}
```

Comment: you don't mean PostAsJsonAsync()?

Comment: Yes! @BrianParker